# download excel file using web api and angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Front-end

```
      var url = baseUrl+ "/api/Home/DownloadReport";
      window.open(url);
```

Back-end

```
     [HttpGet]

    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadReport()
    {
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Test\5\WebApplication1\Report.xlsx"));
      HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream);
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
      System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "myworkbook.xlsx"
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new 
        System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        return result
         }
```

I am trying to download an excel file using web API and angularjs but when I click the download button it opens a new tab with the message as below but does not download the file can someone suggest to me what is wrong with the code.

StatusCode:200,ReasonPhrase:'OK',Version:1.1,Content:System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent,Headers:{Content-Type:application/octet-stream Content Disposition:attachment;filename=myworkbook.xlsx}

I know the question has been asked previously but tried many solutions but was not able to solve issue

Answer (score 0):

#### Front-end

Instead of using `window.open`, uses this workaround:

```js
var url = baseUrl+ "/api/Home/DownloadReport";

var tmp = document.createElement('A');
tmp.href = url;
tmp.type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
tmp.download = 'myworkbook.xlsx';
tmp.click();
```

#### Back-end

Try to use `application/vnd.ms-excel` in the argument of `MediaTypeHeaderValue` constructor.

Comment: I tried the above suggested code.but it shows error like the file format and extension of myworkbook.xlsx doesn't match.the file could be corrupted or unsafe.but the input file on server is good.i also tried to change

Comment: I also tried application/vnd.openxmlformat-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet but it also not worked

Comment: Try to use `StreamContent` instead of `ByteArrayContent`.

Comment: Thank you.i solved it by changing the return type to filereturn and now it is working